# Eloquent consulta con multiples like

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Quiero hacer una consulta que tenga multiples filtros con LIKE.

Le dejo un ejemplo:

```
$ingresosTerminadosDesechados=Ingreso::join('solicitudes','ingresos.solicitud_id','=','solicitudes.id')
        ->join('articulos','ingresos.articulo_id','=','articulos.id')
        ->join('clientes','solicitudes.cliente_id','=','clientes.id')
        ->select('ingresos.id','ingresos.fecha_culminacion','ingresos.total_ingreso', 'ingresos.estatus_ingreso',
            'solicitudes.id as id_solicitud', 'articulos.sku_articulo','articulos.serie_articulo',
            'articulos.peso_articulo','articulos.unidad_masa_articulo')
        ->where('solicitudes.cliente_id','=',$clienteConectado)
        ->where('ingresos.solicitado_envio','=','N')
        ->where('articulos.sku_articulo','LIKE','%'.trim($request->filtro).'%')
        ->orWhere('articulos.serie_articulo','LIKE','%'.trim($request->filtro).'%')
        ->whereIn('ingresos.estatus_ingreso',['Terminado','Desechado'])
        ->orderBy('ingresos.estatus_ingreso','ASC')
        ->get();
```

Con un solo LIKE funciona perfecto, pero si agrego mas campos LIKE, no hace el trabajo adecuadamente, ¿dónde esta el error?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado «no adecuado»?

Comment: No veo error. ¿Si escribieras la consulta en el manejador de base de datos sí te arroja los datos que esperas? ¿Cómo sería la consulta textualmente?

Comment: No serviría poniendo todos esos like en un function?